# java giving incorrect maths answers when given a line of (maths related) code

Tags: java, math

i am trying to run this code in java

```
double health = ((level*level +10000) * (level/150)/6) +100;
```

and it always come out as 100 (or whatever the last number is)
in this instance level = 1 but even replacing the variable level with the number 1 wont fix this. when done right the answer should equal approximately 110 . please help me fix this code so i can continue programming

i have already tried breaking the line up into multiple separate lines of code, but still no fix. granted, this uses some pretty big fractions but it worked before and not all of a sudden it has stopped working. please help me to fix this problem,

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`((level*level +10000) * (level/150)/6)` get's floored off to the nearest number, which is **0**.

So your code should be like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double level = 10.0;

    double health = ((level*level +10000) * (level/150)/6) +100;

    System.out.println(health);
 }
}
```

Comment: It gets floored, not rounded. And you're completely wrong about float vs. double.

Comment: @shmosel. Yeah, forgot the correct word. Changed it. Thanks

Comment: still not working

Comment: @arcturus125 Try the code I provided

Comment: Can the mystery downvoter explain the downvote please?

Comment: The problem is with your level which is an int, so multiply with an int is getting as int, so you are loosing the fraction part, so try using level as double or 

{code}

int level = 1;
double health = ((double)(level*level) + 10000) * (((double)level)/150)/6 + 100;

{code}

Comment: @varra I am using `level` as `double`

Comment: @PritamBanerjee yeah, saw it, suppose if his business requirement doesn't allow him to change the level type to double, he can use explicit casting as I shown.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `level` is an `int`, `level/150` will automatically get floored to a whole number, or 0. You can solve this by changing `level` to a `float`, or by changing `150` to `150f`.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it. i needed to put (double) infront of the fraction

```
double health = ((1*1 +10000) * ((double)1/150)/6) +100;
```

without it the number is too small and the program must assumes it is 0